# Properties of Ackermann's function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, ackermann-function

I want to show the following properties of [Ackermann's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function):

> 1. $A(x,y)>y$.
> 2. $A(x,y+1)>A(x,y)$.
> 3. If $y_2>y_1$, then $A(x,y_2)>A(x,y_1)$.
> 4. $A(x+1, y) \geq A(x,y+1)$.
> 5. $A(x,y)>x$.
> 6. If $x_2>x_1$, then $A(x_2, y)>A(x_1, y)$.
> 7. $A(x+2, y)>A(x,2y)$.

I'm looking for hints to prove the properties $3$ and $6$. I think that I should use properties $2$ and $4$ respectively but I'm unsure how to do so.

**My try for $3$**

By induction on $x$, for the base case $x = 0$ we have:

$y_2 > y_1 \implies A(0,y_2)=y_2+1>y_1+1=A(0,y_1)$

where we have used the inequality in the hypothesis and the definition of the Ackermann's function.

For the inductive hypothesis, assuming the property holds for $x=n$, that means:

$y_2 > y_1 \implies A(n,y_2)>A(n,y_1)$ (I.H)

in the inductive step we want to show that:

$y_2 \implies A(n+1,y_2)>A(n+1,y_1)$.

I don't know how to continue from here.

**My try for $5$**

By $4$, we have:

$A(x+1, y) \geq A(x,y+1)$

So, we have:

$A(x,y) \geq A(x-1, y+1) \geq A(x-2, y+2) \geq \dots \geq A(0,x+y)=x+y+1>x$.

How can I formalize this reasoning.

Comment: probably all these are proved in a book somewhere.... the function is very thoroughly studied over decades....

Answer (score 0):

For $3$, it's simply induction on $2$. Use induction to show that $A(x,y+n)>A(x,y)$, then let $y_2=y+n$ and $y_1=y$.

---

You have the right idea for $5$. Use induction and $4$ to prove $A(n+x,y)\ge A(n,y+x)$ and let $n=0$ to get the desired result.